# Custom variable for ENV always error when deploy, serverless framework

Tags: aws-lambda, serverless-framework, aws-serverless

I'm trying to use S3 service in my project.

I save custom variable & use in my provider property:

```
service: snapnext

custom:
  imagesBucketName: snapnext-images

provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: nodejs6.10
  iamRoleStatements: # IAM permissions granted to all functions
    - Effect: Allow
      Action:
        - S3:GetObject
      Resource:
        - Fn::Join:
            - ''
            - - 'arn:aws:s3:::'
              - '${self:custom.imagesBucketName}/*'
  environment:
    IMAGES_BUCKET_NAME: ${self:custom.imagesBucketName}

functions:
  downloadImage: # Define a new Function
    handler: functions/downloadImage.handler
    events:
      - http:
          path: images
          method: post

resources:
  Resources:
    ImagesBucket:
      Type: AWS::S3::Bucket
      Properties:
        BucketName: ${self:custom.imagesBucketName}
        AccessControl: PublicRead

plugins:
  - serverless-offline
```

When I'm trying to deploy, I'm always getting an error message like this
[image]

Any idea why this happens?
And how to better way to debug in a serverless framework, especially for `.yml` file?

Comment: Did you create the `snapnext-images` bucket before you tried to deploy your serverless application? For example through the web console or in a similar manner?

Answer (score 1):

You've configured serverless to create a bucket with the name `snapnext-images` and when it tries to do it it can't because... it already exists.

Provided the bucket name is available (bucket names are shared with everyone), either:

- Ensure the bucket doesn't exist before first deployment so serverless can do its job; or
- Don't define a bucket for creation and use your existing bucket; or
- Pick a different name if you want to create a new bucket and keep the existing bucket.

This has nothing to do with custom variables.

Comment: hi Alex, thx for u response.

I already try to delete bucket in s3 services & cloud formation. after that, I'm running command serverless remove in my terminal.

When I'm trying to deploy again, I get the same error message

Comment: @EndySantoso the bucket definitely exists. If this bucket is yours ensure its deleted, if its not yours you'll have to pick another name -- buckets cross region and accounts.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to create the s3 resource when you deploy your stack. You will get this error only of the bucket name already exists. The bucket names should be unique across regions and accounts. 
You need to be careful/mindful with creating s3 bucket resources in cloud formation.

- Make sure it doesn't exist before deployment
  Many times deleting stack doesn't delete the S3 bucket created with the stack if the bucket has objects/files in it. You need to write a custom lambda trigged on delete bucket event to delete all the contents before deleting the bucket.